# curlUp and curlDown Animation from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to go from one view controller to another with the use of page curl up animation; but when my second controller loads, it hides the collection view from it. This is my code:

```
OffersVC *Offers = [[OffersVC alloc]init];
    Offers = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Offers"];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:Offers.view];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add animation as below and check

```
  UIView *mainview = self.view.window;

OffersVC *Offers = [[OffersVC alloc]init];
Offers = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Offers"];

[UIView transitionWithView:mainview
              duration:kAnimationViewTransition 
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
            animations:^{
                [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
                [mainview addSubview: offers.view];
            } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self presentModalViewController:offers animated:NO];
            }
];
```

Comment: While this answer may indeed solve the original question. it would be really helpful if you provide some explanation and context.